# How to carry out multiple SI acquisition automatically?

Tags: dm-script, data-acquisition

I would like to write a Gatan DigitalMicrograph script to acquire multiple EELS spectrum images continuously. If there is a command to obtain Spectrum Image (SI) data, and store the three-dimensional image to an array, I will achieve my plan. However, I could not find appropriate commands for SI imaging mode from reference manual. What command should I use in this case? Do you have a helpful knowledge for my purpose? It will be appreciated if you share some wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short demo-script of how to use the SIAcquisition commands for multiple iterations of SI acquisition and "renaming" the acquired data sets.

```
// Assumptions:  
// -  GMS 2.3 used
// -  Valid survey image and ROI already assigned
// -  SI array size already defined
// -  Signals and other SI settings made

number SIx, SIy 
SIGetFieldValue( "2D Array, X samples", SIx )
SIGetFieldValue( "2D Array, Y samples", SIy )
Result("\n SI size:"+ SIx + "x" + SIy )

// Start SI
number nSI = 3
for (number i=0; i<nSI; i++ )
{
    SIInvokeButton( "Start/Stop", 1 )
    while(SIIsAcquisitionActive()) yield()
    sleep(0.5)          // Small delay needed to allow DM finish SI acquisition clean-up

    // Find (and rename) SI DataSets
    number nImgDoc = CountImageDocuments()
    string findStr = "Spectrum Image"
    for (number d=0; d<nImgDoc; d++ )
    {
        string docName = GetImageDocument(d).ImageDocumentGetName()
        if ( find(docName,findStr) == (len(docName)-len(findStr)) )
        {
            GetImageDocument(d).ImageDocumentSetName( docName + "#"+(d+1) )
        }   
    }
}
OKDialog( "Done" )
```

Comment: I would like to appreciate your help very much. I was able to complete the writing a script I desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the spectrum-imaging plugin installed, then the F1 help file will have a section on STEM SI scripting commands here...

[image]

---

However, the commands described there will allow the acquisition  of one SI after the other. Each will start anew with the same overhead you get when repeatedly starting SI acquisition via the UI.

I've got the impression you want to get a "faster" repeated SI.
Unfortunately, no commands exist which could easily give you that.

However, you might be able to create a "work-arround" solution by the following idea (untested):

> - Set up a STEM SI with multiple-frames 
>   (*Each frame pass will be summed into the same container*)
> - Use the "SI HookUP Scripts" on a per-pixel basis (*Pixel end*) to catch the "last" acquired SI point (before the new frame starts). Use this to copy the existing data into a new container and set the orignal back to zero.
>     
>     **Alternative:**
> - You might also be able to use the "*Correction start*" HookUp script point, if you set spatial drift-correction to perform at end of frame...

The above will only work with software-synchronized SI's. For hardware-synchronized, it becomes more tricky, but you might be able to do something similar with a "ImageUpdate" event-listener.

Comment: Thank you very much for your promt and useful suggestion. According to your nice advice, I try to control SI mode by using a "HookUp" script. But I have a question yet.  How should I write a script to access the values of 3D array containing SI data on appropriate timing specified by a HookUp script? I'm sorry for bothering you because I'm a beginner of dm-scripting.

Comment: Alternatively, I have another question. I think that we can perform spectrum imaging by direct scripting without using SI mode as a brute force technique. Probably, the beam position can be controlled by a DigiScan command and corresponding EELS signal can also be acquired by a CCD acquisition command; and thus I feel such kind of scripting duplicate SI mode. Is this bad idea? By my present idea, pixel-by-pixel EELS acquisition is going to be achieved by using DSScanSubRegion command and CCD acquisition command. But  DSScanSubRegion command can not select the scanning area as a single pixel.

Comment: @kachigusa It is not a bad idea per se, but it is a lot of work and will yield you something inferior to the current SI package. (f.e. no drift correction, slower, no mulitple simultaneous signals etc.). I don't think I understood your other question correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. According to your advice, I'm going to try to write a "SI HookUP Scripts". But I don't know how to access the existing data (i.e., spectrum imaging data being recorded under multiple frames recording mode). If I can access it easily,  the existing data could be copied to another new container, as you mentioned.